# C2440 static_cast cannot convert from base class to derived class

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, static-cast

I am attempting to understand why casting from a base class to an derived class using pointers compiles fine, but casting using non-pointer object produces the error C2440.

Below I have a base class `ThreadedMessage` that is inherited by class `GPSMessage`.

```
struct ThreadedMessage
{
  ThreadedMessage()
    : m_Type(0), m_ID(0)
  { }

  ThreadedMessage(uint Type, uint ID = 0) :
    m_Type(Type), m_ID(ID)
  { }

  uint m_Type;
  uint m_ID;
};    

struct GPSMessage : public ThreadedMessage
{
  GPSMessage()
    : ThreadedMessage()
  { }

  GPSMessage(double lat, double lon)
    : ThreadedMessage(1), m_lat(lat), m_lon(lon)
  { }

  double m_lat;
  double m_lon;
};
```

In `myFunction` I am attempting to cast from the base class to the derived class.

```
void myFunction(const ThreadedMessage& msg)
{
  const GPSMessage* message = static_cast<const GPSMessage*>(&msg); // Compiles fine
  const GPSMessage message1 = static_cast<const GPSMessage>(msg);   // Error C2440
}
```

The call to `myFunction()` looks like this:

```
GPSMessage msg(21.123, 12.321);
myFunction(msg);
```

When I compile, the casting of a pointer compiles fine, but the non-pointer casting fails with the following error:

> error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const ThreadedMessage' to 'const GPSMessage' No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Why am I unable to cast from the base class to the derived class with non-pointer variables?

Compiler is MS VS 2008 C++.

Yes, I have looked at other similar SO questions, but the ones I have read don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: On a side note: did you consider upgrading MS VC 2008 to something which is a bit more modern? Newer versions of MSVC improved a lot on error reporting and following the C++ standard. Not to mention support for c++11, c++14 and c++17

Comment: MS VS 2008 was the last version of VS to support the system I am working on. Also for many systems C++11 and later is not allowed or supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two casts have differing meaning.

The first cast:

```
const GPSMessage* message = static_cast<const GPSMessage*>(&msg); // Compiles fine
```

This means that `msg` is actually a `GPSMessage` (or a derived) object. You ask the compiler to threat `msg` as a `GPSMessage`. No new object will be created, `message` will point to `msg`. If `msg` is not actually a `GPSMessage` (or derived), then this cast has Undefined Behavior.

Btw, the following cast have the same meaning (casting to a reference):

```
const GPSMessage& message = static_cast<const GPSMessage&>(msg); // same meaning, which results in a reference instead of a pointer
```

About the second cast:

```
const GPSMessage message1 = static_cast<const GPSMessage>(msg);   // Error C2440
```

This means, that you create a *new* object, `message1` from `msg`. You should give a way to make this conversion possible. For example, you should create a constructor for `GPSMessage` which has a `ThreadedMessage` parameter:

```
struct GPSMessage {
    GPSMessage(const ThreadedMessage &); // needed constructor
};
```

Or create a conversion operator for `ThreadedMessage` to `GPSMessage`:

```
struct ThreadedMessage {
    operator GPSMessage(); // conversion operator
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In the function the compiler only knows that `msg` is a reference to a ***`ThreadedMessage`***, it doesn't know what's really passed as an argument inside the function.

Think about what happened if you passed a reference to an *actual* `ThreadedMessage` object? Or a reference to another object from some other inherited class?

To cast from an `ThreadedMessage` object to a `GPSMessage` object, a conversion is needed, and there's no such conversion possible (the `ThreadedMessage` class doesn't have a conversion operator, and `GPSMessage` doesn't have a suitable constructor).

The only solution is to cast pointers or references to another pointer or reference. Like you do in the pointer example, or by doing e.g.

```
const GPSMessage& message1 = static_cast<const GPSMessage&>(msg);
```

---

If you really want to cast to a `GPSMessage` *object*, not reference or pointer, then the best solution is to use a conversion constructor:

```
class GPSMessage : public ThreadedMessage
{
public:
    ...
    explicit GPSMessage(const ThreadedMessage& tm)
        : GPSMessage(static_cast<const GPSMessage&>(tm))  // Invoke copy-constructor
    {}
    ...
};
```

Using the copy-constructor is nice, but it requires that the `tm` argument really *is* a reference to a `GPSMessage` object. Otherwise it's invalid.

---

Another solution is to make the classes *polymorphic* (simplest by making the destructors `virtual`) and use `dynamic_cast` to a pointer. If the result is a null pointer then `msg` wasn't a `GPSMessage` to begin with.

Comment: If one is very very sure of the type of `msg`, then `const GPSMessage message1 = static_cast<const GPSMessage&>(msg);` will work even without modifying `GPSMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about virtual destructors. It reminded me that the all of the classes were missing virtual destructors.